# Converter um número inteiro vindo do banco de dados em um Array

Tags: php, mysql, array, string

Quero converter um número inteiro vindo do BD em um Array, por exemplo:

- Eu tenho o número de entregas cadastrado no BD, vamos supor que a produção 'x' seja concluída em 5 entregas.
- esse número 5 é cadastrado no BD como uma String, um número inteiro.
- quando no sistema o usuário vai entregando a produção, ele tem que informar pra qual entrega ele está produzindo.

Dai eu gostaria de puxar um Select de 1 a 5 (que é o número de entregas nesse exemplo) .Alguém sabe como faço para o PHP verificar que o número 5 do exemplo pode ser lido de 1 a 5??

Comment: Está (muito) confuso o que quer.

Comment: Você quer adicionar N `options` do `<select>` baseado na útlima/maior número entrega?

Comment: Galera, obrigado pela ajuda de todos, mas o código do amigo rray resolveu, era bem simples mesmo:

<?php
   $inicio = 1;
   $ultimo = 5;
   $arr = range($inicio, $ultimo);

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($arr);
?>

Comment: Marque a resposta dele como a correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), gera um array baseado em um intervalo, basta informar o valor inicial e o limite, caso precise de um intervalo diferente de 1 adicione o terceiro parametro assim o valor do array pode ser gerado de 2 em 2 ou intervalo desejado.

```
<?php
   $inicio = 1;
   $ultimo = 5
   $arr = range($inicio, $ultimo);

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($arr);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: Seu código resolveu meu problema e salvou minha vida. Deus lhe pague em euros kkkkk muito obrigado

Comment: `$skills['adivinhacao']++;` :D

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia exemplificar com o próprio código que está utilizando, isso iria facilitar muito, para mim ficou confuso o que quer, se pudesse dizer como está a situação agora e como quer, seria bem mais fácil.

**Método 1: Altere o Banco de dados!**

Você pode alterar a DB para INT:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY coluna INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Depois, basta dar um SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE entregas >= 1 and entregas <= 5
```

**Método 2: Loop!**

Se não, faça um loop, porém não recomendo:

```
// Pega tudo do MySQL (SELECT entregas FROM tabela WHERE 1)
// No caso, usando o nome $SQL
if((int)$SQL['entregas'] >= 1 and (int)$SQL['entregas'] <= 5){
echo $SQL['entregas'];
}
```

Depois de ler e reler, creio que sua dúvida possa ser outra...